# Display scaling randomly switches to %200 when I resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 with the 4.20 kernel on a UHD laptop with an Nvidia Quadro P4200 graphics card, and Nvidia's proprietary drivers version 415. I am running gtk3 and the Gnome on Xorg desktop.

Whenever I suspend the laptop (closing the lid for a few minutes or longer, or timing out through inactivity), and then resume to log back in the logging screen will randomly be higher or lower resolution (roughly 50%-50% chance of either). If I log back in this change in resolution follows to Gnome Shell on Xorg, and I have to go to Settings > Devices > Display > Scale and manually change back to my preferred 100% (from 200%).

**How can I make the 100% scaling stick through suspend?**

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? This has started to happen to me. What kicked this off for me was a new HP Pavilion 32" monitor. No change in graphics card. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.